# Derivative of double integral using Leibniz integral rule

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, leibniz-integral-rule

How can I perform derivative of double integral

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\int_{t-\mathrm d1}^t \int_h^t f(s) \,\mathrm ds\,\mathrm dh$$

Can I apply a Leibniz rule of some form? How?

Comment: Do you know what the answer is supposed to be? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\int_h^tf(x)ds = F(t)-F(h)$ with $F'(t)=f(t)$. Then

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\int_{\color{red}{t-\mathrm d_1}}^{\color{blue}{t}} \int_h^t f(s) \,\mathrm ds\,\mathrm dh&=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\int_{\color{red}{t-\mathrm d_1}}^{\color{blue}{t}}  (F(t)-F(h))\,\mathrm dh\\
&=\int_{t-\mathrm d_1}^{t}  \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(F(t)-F(h))\,\mathrm dh\\
&+\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(t)\times  (F(t)-F(t))\\
&-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(t-\mathrm d_1)\times (F(t)-F(t-\mathrm d_1))\\
&=\int_{t-\mathrm d_1}^{t}  f(t)\,\mathrm dh-F(t)+F(t-\mathrm d_1)\\
&=(t-t+d_1)f(t)+F(t)-F(t-\mathrm d_1)\\
&=d_1f(t)-\left(F(t)-F(t-\mathrm d_1)\right)\\
\end{align}

Comment: Why do both Maple and Mathematica answer $$\mathrm d_{{1}}f \left( t \right) -\int_{t-\mathrm d_{{1}}}^{t}\!f \left( s \right) 
\,{\rm d}s=\mathrm d_{{1}}f \left( t \right) -F \left( t \right) +F \left( t-\mathrm d
_{{1}} \right) 
$$ though?

Comment: @Leponzo Just came back to this and fixed it: thank you very much for the comment.

Answer (score 4):

The [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) can be applied.

Let $\int_{h}^{t}\!f \left( s \right) \,{\rm d}s = F(t,h)$.

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\int_{t-\mathrm d1}^t \int_h^t f(s) \,\mathrm ds\,\mathrm dh &= 
{\frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}}\int_{t-\mathrm d_{{1}}}^{t}F \left( t,h
 \right) \,{\rm d}h\\
&= F(t,t)\frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(t) - F(t,t-\mathrm d_1)\frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(t - \mathrm d_1) + \int_{t-\mathrm d_{{1}}}^{t} \frac {\partial}{\partial t} F \left( t,h
 \right) \,{\rm d}h\\
&= 0 - F(t,t-\mathrm d_1) + \int_{t-\mathrm d_{{1}}}^{t} f(t)\,{\rm d}h\\
&= \boxed{-\int_{t-\mathrm d_{{1}}}^{t} f(s)\,{\rm d}s + \mathrm d_1\,f(t)}\\
\end{align}

Note that this is the same as what Mathematica and Maple give.

Comment: Where you have $F(t,t)$, @math-fun has $F(t,h)$ in effect; likewise for $F(t,t-d_1)$ the other has $F(t-d_1,h)$.  That's wrong (that is, math-fun's answer is wrong).  Perhaps the highlighting, instead of revealing the error, masks it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Just came back to this and fixed it: thank you very much for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Set $$\int_h^t f(s)\mathrm{d}s=F(t)$$
Then apply Leibniz twice

Comment: thanx. can u elaborate?